# How to Add Server Explorer to App_Data in Visual studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to add Server Explorer object in `App_Data` How can I add into `App_Data` since for me

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server**

Is not appearing due to company security may be.

[image]

Is there any other way to add in `App_Data`?

Also in property window I can only see `CaseSenstive` and `Owner` Not `PrimaryFilePath`

Answer (score 0):

You should right-click the file and select properties.

[image: Path]

Comment: For me its not appearing PrimaryFilePAth I can only see CaseSensetive and owner

Comment: Check this post:
[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603473/why-is-mdf-file-not-appearing-in-the-app-data-folder)